# Git `format-patch` returns nothing

Tags: git

I am trying to create a patch for a commit in my repository.

- System: Windows 10
- Tools Git Windows Desktop and Git Shell `git --version => git version 2.10.1.windows.1`

When I try to create the patch I go:

```
git format-patch master
git format-patch master -o C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop
git format-patch master --stdout > C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MyPatch.patch
```

In all 3 cases, I get nothing. In the first 2 cases, no file is saved in the locations I specify. In the third case, the generated file is 0 bytes.

#### State of my repository

I have pushed everything to master. So I have no more local unstaged or staged commits. Everything is on the server.

Also, if I change a file and have unstaged changes, still it does not work.

I've also tried:

```
git format-patch <ccommit-sha>
```

Using the SHA hash of a commit I pushed. Still does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create patch you need to specify what should be used to create it. If you want to create patch using last commit from main branch just call
`git format-patch -1 main`.

In case you will need to create patch (patches) for some specific commit, a SHA-1 value can be used in place of the branch name.

For more information, please check [format-patch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch).

It might be worth of mentioning that if you will use SHA-1 hash of a commit that is after your current commit (later timestamp),

This is caused by the way patches are created. Git documentation for [git-format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) says the patch is technically output of the execution of

```
diff -p stat
```

which [creates a diff between a commit and its parent](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff). The parent is a key in this case. If you want to create a patch between your current repository state (for example checked out comit) and one that is in the future, it's not possible, because that future commit is not a parent, but a child.

Comment: It is working. Thanks. But how to specify a SHA for a specific commit???

Comment: Simply put SHA-1 value in place of 'master'. Also you can use -<n> switch (in my example it's -1) to define the "distance" for the patch.

Comment: Why doesn't this work with the hash of a *future* commit in the same branch?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus what do you mean by "future commit"?

Comment: A commit that is in the future compared to the checked-out commit in the timeline tree

Comment: @MarkJeronimus this is caused by the way pathces are created. Git documentation says the patch is technicaly output of the execution of `diff -p stat`, which creates a diff between a commit and its parent. The parent is a key in this case. If you want to create a patch between your current repository state (for example checked out comit) and one that is in the future, it's not possible, because that future commit is not a parent, but a child.

Source: 
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff